# cannot deploy to heroku using google map api dependency

Tags: reactjs, express, heroku, mern

Heroku errors:

```
Total 13 (delta 9), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote: -----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote:        
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:        
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote:        
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  16.x
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
remote:        Resolving node version 16.x...
remote:        Downloading and installing node 16.16.0...
remote:        Using default npm version: 8.11.0
remote:        
remote: -----> Installing dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules
remote:        npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
remote:        npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
remote:        npm ERR! While resolving: @reach/combobox@0.16.5
remote:        npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
remote:        npm ERR! node_modules/react
remote:        npm ERR!   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
remote:        npm ERR!   peer react@"^16.8 || ^17 || ^18" from @react-google-maps/api@2.12.0
remote:        npm ERR!   node_modules/@react-google-maps/api
remote:        npm ERR!     @react-google-maps/api@"^2.12.0" from the root project
remote:        npm ERR!   9 more (@testing-library/react, react-avatar, react-dom, ...)
remote:        npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
remote:        npm ERR! peer react@"^16.8.0 || 17.x" from @reach/combobox@0.16.5
remote:        npm ERR! node_modules/@reach/combobox
remote:        npm ERR!   @reach/combobox@"^0.16.5" from the root project
remote:        npm ERR! 
remote:        npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@17.0.2
remote:        npm ERR! node_modules/react
remote:        npm ERR!   peer react@"^16.8.0 || 17.x" from @reach/combobox@0.16.5
remote:        npm ERR!   node_modules/@reach/combobox
remote:        npm ERR!     @reach/combobox@"^0.16.5" from the root project
```

I am trying to deploy this react mern-stack app to heroku for class, which uses certain google map api and dependencies. I tried `--legacy-peer-deps` and even `--force` (force completely broke my code), tried almost everything. Nothing seems to be working. Been trying at this for a while now and am completely blocked. I don't know what else to do. I appreciate any insight to this.

Heres my package.json

```
{
  "name": "find-furry-friends",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "engines": {
    "node": "16.x"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@hookform/resolvers": "^2.9.4",
    "@reach/combobox": "^0.16.5",
    "@react-google-maps/api": "^2.12.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "mongoose": "^6.4.0",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "petfinder-client": "^1.0.2",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-avatar": "^5.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.0.2",
    "react-file-base64": "^1.0.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "react-tilty": "^2.0.3",
    "serve-favicon": "^2.5.0",
    "use-places-autocomplete": "^4.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4",
    "yup": "^0.32.11"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3001"
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `@reach/combobox` wants an older version of React (either 16 0r 17) but you have React 18.2.0 installed at the top level of your `package.json`. Try downgrading React to version 17:

```
npm install react@17
```

Then push to Heroku again.

Comment: I'm sorry that didn't work and caused my code to break... get this `react-dom.development.js:26146 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isBatchingLegacy')`

Comment: Is this a public project on GitHub that you can post a link to?